# Corona SDK: The TabBar Doesn't Load @2x Images..?

Tags: xcode, cocoa, coronasdk

Why the tabbar doesn't load '@2x' image automatically on iPhone4 or 5? 
Here is my code:

```
local function init()
--Create a group that contains the entire screen and tab bar
mainView = display.newGroup()   

--Create a group that contains the screens beneath the tab bar
tabView = display.newGroup()    
mainView:insert(tabView)

loadScreen("info-moregames")

tabBar = viewController.newTabBar{
        background = "UI_INFO/tabBar.png",  --tab bar background
        default = {"UI_INFO/pogi_no.png","UI_INFO/noads_no.png","UI_INFO/share_no.png","UI_INFO/star_no.png","UI_INFO/restore_no.png","UI_INFO/back_no.png"},
        over = {"UI_INFO/pogi_yes.png","UI_INFO/noads_yes.png","UI_INFO/share_yes.png","UI_INFO/star_yes.png","UI_INFO/restore_yes.png","UI_INFO/back_yes.png"},
        tabs = {"More", "No Ads", "Share","Rate us","Restore","back"}, --names to appear under each tab icon
        onRelease = showScreen  --function to execute when pressed
    }
mainView:insert(tabBar)

tabBar.selected()

return true
```

end

Answer (score 0):

If you have a config.lua file like above, your images will be automaticaly scaled.

```
application = {
    content = {
        width = ***,
        height = ***, 
        scale = "letterBox",
}
```

If you have a config.lua file like above, you can use different images for different resolutions. Note that, you should have two images for that. For example, you have an image temp.png which is 20x20. Then you should have another temp@2x.png which is 40x40. In this way you can get better images with better resolution. And also, 1.5 value means that if the device's screen is 1.5 times more then your desired resolution, use images with @2x ending.

```
application = {
    content = {
        width = ***,
        height = ***, 
        scale = "letterBox",

        imageSuffix = {
            ["@2x"] = 1.5,
        }
    },
}
```

Comment: so what should be entered as 'width' and 'height'?

Comment: That depends on you.. If you are creating an iPhone app, you can set
width = 320, height = 480, OR width = 640, height = 960

Comment: I checked, I think I did this already. It works for other images, but not the TabBar.